# Any ways to implement ads on list view of android?

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-listview, admob

I am trying to implement ads on listview. But unfortunately, it is not happening. Especially when I try to implement this.

```
    'implementation 'com.github.clockbyte:admobadapter:1.x.x'
```

it gives me an error and the emulator crashes. Is there any other ways to implement native ads on list view

Answer (score 1):

I will write it step by step 
1. Create your own custom adapter (by extending BaseAdapter) which will be shown as listview items
2. Create another layout resource file for showing native ad (design should be similar to the custom adapter created in above step) 
3. In the getView method do something as follows (for showing ad at 2nd position)

```
if (position == 1) {
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.native_ad_adapter, null);
    NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
} else {
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_list, null);
    TextView bigtxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    ...
    ...
}
```

Here your custom adapter is my_custom_list 
You will see the ads are loading. But there is a small problem, the actual item of list at position 1 will not be shown. 
4. For that, add an extra item to the list before populating the ListView. I have used ArrayList so I could do it easily. My approach is as follows

```
arrayList1.add(1,"ad here");
listview1.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(callerView.getContext(), arrayList1.toArray(new String[arrayList1.size()])));
```